# returning an object by function without using & (c++)

Tags: c++, function, class

Why do you return an object with function by using &?
For example, lets have a look at the following classes and function:

```
class Point
{
public:
Point(int x, int y);
int getX() const;
int getY() const;
void setX(int x);
void setY(int y);
void print() const;
private:
int x, y;
};


class Circle
{
public:
Circle(int x, int y, int r, int color);
int getColor() const;
void setColor(int color);
bool contains(const Point &p) const;
void print() const;
private:
const Point center;
int radius, color;
};

class Collection
{
public:
Collection(int radius, int width, int height, int color);
~Collection();
Circle& getCircleAt(const Point &p);
void print() const;
private:
int count;
Circle **circles;
};


Circle& Collection::getCircleAt(const Point &p)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        if (circles[i]->contains(p))
          return *(circles)[i];
}
```

The function above returnes a circle.
**In the function getCirclet, why is the sign & is necessary ? Why can't I omit it?**

Comment: The symbol `&` can mean many different things in many different programming languages. Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You question is still very unclear. What do you mean by "type class"? What do you mean by returning a type class? You do know what the `&` symbol can mean in C++? What does it mean in the context of your problem? Is it a bitwise AND operator? A reference to something? The address-of operator?

Comment: I have just edited my post. sorry.

Comment: That function is broken, as it doesn't return anything if `p` isn't found. That will inevitably cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: @NOA_ROTH in this case `&` means reference to an object of class `Circle`.

Comment: Why do you think you can't omit it?

Comment: You *can* omit it, but then you will return a *copy* of the `Circle` object. Which means you can't use it to modify the original `Circle` object. It all depends on how you want to use the function and the object it returns.

Answer (score 1):

In your function

```
Circle& Collection::getCircleAt(const Point &p)
```

the return type `Circle&` means that a reference to on object of type `Circle` will be returned. If you declared your function

```
Circle Collection::getCircleAt(const Point &p)
```

with the same body, then a copy of the object would be returned, if a copy constructor is available. This means in the first case, if you modify the returned object, this will modify the object contained in the `Collection`, while in the second case, only the copy will be modified.

Note that references cannot be `NULL`, so you have a problem if your particular function is called with a `Point` that is not inside any `Circle`. Returning nothing at all, as you do now, is not an option.